# react-split-pane with Material-UI persistent drawer not resizing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

react-split-pane with Material-UI persistent drawer not resizing when drawer opens. You can see it here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/z11w886yx

Is this an issue between react-split-pane and Material-UI or can it it be fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The drawer is drawn over the whole page. The normal text shrinks artificially, see the `appBarShift` CSS rule with the left margin:

```
appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
```

This leaves a bunch of blank area below the drawer. You need to do something similar if you want the split-based content to shrink too.